# What can you about $X$ if $X$ $\cup${$X$}=$X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can say that there is a paradox. There can not be $X$. So, my question is that if a person say that why there is a paradox? then, what can I say for proof?

Comment: $X\in X\cup \{X\}$, so $X\in X$.  This is not allowed by the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks.

Comment: There are versions of set theory where we *can* have $X=X\cup \{X\}$. However, under ZFC, the *axiom of regularity* forbids this from occurring.

Comment: What makes you think it is a paradox?